How to prevent WorkManager from restarting when force-stop
I'm developing a timer app using WorkManager.
When the timer starts, it runs in the doWork method of WorkManager.
However, while the timer is running in the background through doWork, if the user closes the app and force-stop the background service, when the app is relaunched, the timer starts again from the beginning.
I would like the WorkManager not to run when the app is relaunched after the user forcibly stops the background service or turns off and then restarts the device while the timer is running.
I am managing WorkManager creation and control in the viewModel.
When the timer starts, it is initiated via enqueueUniqueWork and transitions to the RUNNING state, allowing the timer to execute.
Even if the app is closed, it maintains the RUNNING state, but it seems to transition to the ENQUEUED state if the background service is forcibly stopped.
Even if it transitions from ENQUEUED to RUNNING state and the background service is forcibly terminated, the work resumes.
To prevent this, I have implemented a method in the viewModel to initialize WorkManager and cancel the work if its state is not RUNNING.
However, due to the asynchronous nature of the operation, sometimes it becomes RUNNING during initialization and cancellation, causing the work to resume, while other times it remains in the ENQUEUED state and the work is cancelled, yielding the desired outcome.
since it is mostly in the RUNNING state, I cannot achieve the desired result.
I want to implement a solution where the work does not resume when the background service is forcibly terminated.
Below is my current code.
worker
class TimerWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        val minutes = inputData.getInt("minutes", 0)

        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(minutes.toLong())
        setForeground(createForegroundInfo(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis()))
        return try {

            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                Thread.sleep(500)
                val leftTime = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis()
                setForeground(createForegroundInfo(leftTime))
                println(leftTime)
            }
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    private fun createForegroundInfo(leftTime: Long): ForegroundInfo {

        val notification = NotificationCompat
            .Builder(applicationContext, NotificationHelper.CHANNEL_ID_FOREGROUND)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Backgrounding... $leftTime")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build()

        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            ForegroundInfo(999, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE)
        } else {
            ForegroundInfo(999, notification)
        }
    }
}

ViewModel
    private val workManager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).apply {
        val workState = getWorkInfosForUniqueWork("timer").get().first()
        println("current state : ${workState.state}")
        if (workState.state != WorkInfo.State.RUNNING) {
            cancelUniqueWork("timer")
        }
    }

    fun startTimerAlarm() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val timerWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TimerWorker>()
                .setInputData(workDataOf("minutes" to _state.value.hour * 60 + _state.value.minute))
                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()

            workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
                "timer",
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                timerWorkRequest
            )
        }
    }


What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish because this does not sound like an appropriate use of WorkManager

@tyczj
I want to run a timer in the background so that an alarm goes off when the time comes, and I want to be able to continue monitoring the timer's status even if the app is closed. Is using WorkManager not a good approach? If not, how can I implement it?

You should be using AlarmManager for that, thats its exact purpose

Isn't it impossible to know the remaining time of the current timer when using AlarmManager? When the app is closed and reopened, there's no way to display the remaining time of the current timer and how it's decreasing in real-time. Is there a way to know the currently registered alarms in AlarmManager? I couldn't find it when I searched, but if it exists, what keyword should I use to search? @tyczj

If you need to know the remaining time then you need to store the time it was set is shared preferences or something and then clear it when the alarm fires. It is correct you are unable to get the scheduled alarms from alarm manager itself so you must persist somewhere when an alarm was set

Before using WorkManager, I implemented it using AlarmManager. It seems the best approach is to use the time stored in the Datastore and the current time to update the UI when the app is reopened. Currently, I am using setAlarmClock to trigger the alarm at the exact time, but I noticed that it is not accurate for operations under 5 seconds. How can this issue be resolved? @tyczj

setAlarmClock should work, I am not aware of any limitation to it but setExact is another alternative and what I typically use

I apologize for asking so many questions. I understand that starting from Android 14, permission for alarms and reminders is required to use setAlarmClock. Without this permission, setAlarmClock does not function properly. However, other timer apps do not require the alarms and reminders permission. Therefore, I thought my approach might be wrong. Is there a way to use setAlarmClock without the alarms and reminders permission? The Samsung Clock app does not check for this permission either. @tyczj

no you need that permission but also if this is an app that is suppose to go on the play store it will probably get rejected because its not alarm lock so best to use setExact. You can check to documentation for more information about that

Then how do other timer apps like the Samsung Clock app implement their timer functionality to work accurately without the alarms and reminders permission? I discovered this while trying to obtain the alarms and reminders permission within the app at runtime. Additionally, is there a way to obtain the alarms and reminders permission at runtime within the app? Is directing the user to the settings app the only way? @tyczj

Samsungs app is a system app built into the os they can do whatever. Yes the only way is to ask for permission at runtime for android 13+

Thank you so much for your help. Are you saying that for Android 13+, we need to direct users to the settings app at runtime to obtain the alarms and reminders permission? I understand that notification permissions can be obtained within the app, but I want to confirm that this is not possible for alarms and reminders permissions. Lastly, it's still a mystery to me how some other timer apps on the Play Store don't require the alarms and reminders permission, aside from Samsung's app. @tyczj

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/schedule-exact-alarms
